# Android Client and Java server 'Java.net.ConnectException'

Tags: java, android, sockets

I made a super simple server on my Windows Machine that waits for a client, and when connected, all it does is get a message and prints it to the Console.

When I run a Server code on my computer, and then run another Client application, it works fine. However, when I run the exact same client code(except for a few changes that are necessary) on my Android Phone(connected via USB), it doesn't work.

The IP address for my PC is correct and the port is free, I've been getting this error message:

> W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.10.104 (port 1755) from /:: (port 42102): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

My server.java that runs on my PC is

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    // Initialize everything
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private DataInputStream in =null;

    //constructor with port
    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);

            System.out.println("Server started, waiting for Client...");

            socket = server.accept();

            System.out.println("Client accepted");

            in =new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while (!line.equals("Over")) {
                try {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Closing connection");

            //CLosing connections
            socket.close(); in .close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(1755);
    }
}
```

This is the client code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Message_shower;
    EditText text_place;
    TextView messageStatus;
    Button send_btn;

    // Initialize sockets and IO streams
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 1755;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.10.104";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text_place = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        messageStatus = findViewById(R.id.messageStatus);
        send_btn = findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        // Shows recent sent message
        Message_shower = findViewById(R.id.Message_shower);

        // Establish a connection
        send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Sender().execute();
            }
        });

    }
    // Close connections
    private void onClose() {
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    class Sender extends AsyncTask < Void,
    Void,
    Integer > {

        private Exception e1;
        private Exception e2;
        String input;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            EditText text_place = findViewById(R.id.editText);

            // Takes input from terminal
            input = text_place.getText().toString();
            Message_shower.setText(input);
            System.out.println("Reached here\n");
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void...params) {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                // Sends output to the socket
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                this.e1 = e;
            }
            try {
                out.writeUTF(input);

            } catch(Exception h) {
                this.e2 = h;
            }

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (e1 != null) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (e2 != null) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.messageStatus);
            txt.setText("Message Sent");
            text_place.setText("");
            onClose();

        }

    }
}
```

All input is very appreciated, I've tried various ways like turning off the firewall and such but none worked.

Comment: Have you tried it by making your PC discoverable in private networks?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra Hey, thanks for replying, and no, I haven't done that

Comment: , I just checked, it already is discoverable for private networks

Comment: Your server is probably only binding to the loopback address. Try instead binding to "0.0.0.0". If that works then look at your interfaces and figure out which is the one IP address you need to bind to (probably something that starts with "192.168.10")